# How to store part of an Excel file name in a Python integer variable

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have an excel file with the name `LP_Elements_Shocked_202108160517.xlsx`

I would like to pull out this specific part of the file name and store it as an integer `20210816`

The pattern is consistent. All files begin with `LP_Elements_Shocked_` and then are followed by the eight digits I need. And then there will always be 4 more digits I do not need after those

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel('LP_Elements_Shocked_202108160517.xlsx')
```

Comment: What is the pattern you have on all your file names? you can probably use a regular expression. For instance "take the 8 digits following a '_'" would be the regex: `(?<=_)\d{8}`. Search about regular expressions (also called regex), there are plenty of tutorials available.

Comment: The pattern is simple for all of these file names. So I believe regex may be a good solution

Comment: The pattern is consistent. All files begin with ```LP_Elements_Shocked_``` and then are followed by the eight digits I need. And then there will always be 4 more digits I do not need after those

Comment: then you can use the even simpler substring.

Comment: Pac0 is right. `name[20:28]` will do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your pattern always starts with the same string, you can just use a substring (slice the string):

```
filename = 'LP_Elements_Shocked_202108160517.xlsx'

print(filename[20:28]) # prints: '20210816'
```

otherwise you could use a regex for more complex patterns.

For the part (from the comments) where you want to keep the filename with each dataframe, the simplest would be to add a column filled with the filename to each dataframe you read (by itself, pandas does not keep track of the filename of the excel file).

See this related Q&A: [read_excel into data frame and keep file name as column (Pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668319/read-excel-into-data-frame-and-keep-file-name-as-column-pandas)

Comment: Thank you! How can I access the filename from the pandas dataframe that I created in the initial question?

Comment: ah, this part might then be very related to this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668319/read-excel-into-data-frame-and-keep-file-name-as-column-pandas. You may need to reorganisethe code that reads your files so you add the name to the dataframe after having read the file.

Comment: Yes, just to clarify, I can't hardcode the file name because while the pattern stays the same the filenames will change

Comment: yes, obviously, otherwise you already know that the result would be "20210816" :)

Comment: There may not be a way to get from the dataframe to the filename as Pandas doesn't seem to keep the source information as an attribute of the dataframe

Comment: Does your application/script only have access to instantiated dataframe objects, and not the filenames?

Comment: yes, indeed @axolotl, OP must manually add it to the dataframe. Or create some wrapper class to store both.

Comment: Perhaps a case for the walrus operator? `pd.read_excel((filename := 'LP_Elements_Shocked_202108160517.xlsx'))`

Comment: @axolotl isnt this line static and wont work if the file name changes to different numbers?

Comment: @FinDev it is not clear what constraint you are dealing with. The obvious way to store a filename is as a string, but it seems you are unable to do that.

Comment: you can also simply add the filename to a list each time you read a data frame.

Comment: Or, if you concatenate various dataframes from several files together, you can add a column on each dataframe with the filename, so each "row" of data would be associated with its original filename (or the date part). See the post linked above

Comment: Ok, I see what you guys are saying now. I think I've worked out the solution!

Answer (score 1):

use `re`

```
import re
file_name = 'LP_Elements_Shocked_202108160517.xlsx'
num = re.findall("\d+", file_name)[0][:-4]
print(num)
```

output

```
20210816
```